# How to refresh only a part of page with Java (like partial in ASP.net)

Tags: jquery, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have a search form, and i would like to display the results under the search form.
I use to do that with Jquery load and asp.net with Partials, so i don't have to reload all the page, just the result div.

I still have my load() working, calling the java method, i get my results in the java method, but i don't know how to pass it to the view?

Answer (score 0):

[JavaServer Faces](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkiow.html) (JSF) can answer your question. 
JSF technology supports Ajax by using a built-in JavaScript resource library that is provided as part of the JavaServer Faces core libraries.

The architectural MVC is in turn dividable as follows:

- M - Entity
- V - JSP/XHTML page
- C - Managed bean